# Testing Rails App running on mac os x from VirtualBox

Tags: windows, macos, networking, cross-browser, virtualbox

I am running a Rails app on server 3000 on my Mac OS X, and am trying (and failing to) connect to it from a Windows XP IE7 VM.

I have tried the following:

NAT and using the ip address provided on the mac through `ifconfig`
Bridged Adapter in promiscuous mode and using the ip address provided on the mac through `ifconfig`
Host Only and using the ip address provided on the mac through `ifconfig`
Bridged Adapter in promiscuous mode and 10.0.2.2:3000 (as outlined here:http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=682519).

None of these appear to be working...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I got this working by leaving the adapter setting on the VM as NAT and adding `http://` in front of the `10.0.2.2:3000` address.

For a while a tried just putting `10.0.2.2:3000` in and it didn't worked.

Hope it helps someone save some time.

Comment: This solution saved me!